# Why python multiprocessing module cause CPU completely run out?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiprocessing launching too many instances of Python VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923706/multiprocessing-launching-too-many-instances-of-python-vm)

I am trying python 2.6 multiprocessing module with this simple code snippet.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(5)
def f(x):
    return x*x

print p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

But this code cause my OS stopped responding.  It looks like the CPU is too busy.
What's wrong with my code?

BTW : it seems that multiprocessing module is a bit dangerous.  I had to restart my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't protecting the entry point at all, so each subprocess is trying to start the same `map` call and so on (into infinity!).  Try the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

See [this section](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) of the module's documentation.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923706/multiprocessing-launching-too-many-instances-of-python-vm