# How to run subset of script in multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a simple function with arguments from a list in a multiprocessing pool in Python 2.7.5 (Windows 7).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

index_lst = []
for idx, item in enumerate(range(10)):
    index_lst.append(idx)

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4)
    print(p.map(f, index_lst))
```

Unfortunately, the entire script gets executed multiple times. How to prevent the list (index_lst) from being created over and over again?

Comment: You'll have to define it somewhere else then. If you just want to save the content of  index_lst just write it to a text file or something.

Comment: This works out for very simple scripts. However, if the task produces greater computational overhead, the positive performance effects of multiprocessing become worthless. Moreover, if the pool has to execute a very large number of processes, even smaller processes outside of the multiprocessing pool add up to produce quite significant overhead.

Comment: Tried locally and it works as expected. The result I get is: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]. What are you trying to do and what do you expect to be the output?

Comment: The problem is that the script is duplicated to execute processes in parallel. This means also the list is created multiple times. If you insert a print statement, you'll see that the entire script is executed multiple times. I'd like to create the list just once and run function f for every of the 10 list elements as a process in multiprocessing pool in parallel.

Comment: problem has already been solved:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641080/python-multiple-copies-of-output-when-using-multiprocessing