# python multiprocess caller (as well as callee) invoked multiple times on windows XP

Tags: python, windows-xp, multiprocess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiprocessing launching too many instances of Python VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923706/multiprocessing-launching-too-many-instances-of-python-vm)

I'm trying to use python multiprocess to parallelize web fetching, but I'm finding that the application calling the multiprocessing gets instantiated multiple times, not just the function I want called (which is a problem for me as the caller has some dependencies on a library that is slow to instantiate - losing most of my performance gains from parallelism).

What am I doing wrong or how is this avoided?

my_app.py:

```
from url_fetcher import url_fetch, parallel_fetch
import my_slow_stuff
```

my_slow_stuff.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import datetime
    urls = ['http://www.microsoft.com'] * 20
    results = parallel_fetch(urls, fn=url_fetch)
    print([x[:20] for x in results])

class MySlowStuff(object):
    import time
    print('doing slow stuff')
    time.sleep(0)
    print('done slow stuff')
```

url_fetcher.py:

```
import multiprocessing
import urllib

def url_fetch(url):
    #return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    return url

def parallel_fetch(urls, fn):
    PROCESSES = 10
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(PROCESSES)
    results = pool.imap(fn, urls, CHUNK_SIZE)
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import datetime
    urls = ['http://www.microsoft.com'] * 20
    results = parallel_fetch(urls, fn=url_fetch)
    print([x[:20] for x in results])
```

partial output:

```
$ python my_app.py
doing slow stuff
done slow stuff
doing slow stuff
done slow stuff
doing slow stuff
done slow stuff
doing slow stuff
done slow stuff
doing slow stuff
done slow stuff
```

...

Comment: Are you observing this on Windows?

Comment: yes I am. And indeed, on my Linux server, it does not exhibit that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python multiprocessing module for Windows behaves slightly differently because Python doesn't implement `os.fork()` on this platform. In particular:

> Safe importing of main module
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).

Here, global `class MySlowStuff` gets always evaluated by newly started child processes on Windows. To fix that `class MySlowStuff` should be defined only when `__name__ == '__main__'`.

See [16.6.3.2. Windows](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, as soon as you mentioned windows, I knew I'd (mis)read that section thinking it was pertaining to the callee.

Answer (score 0):

The multiprocessing module on windows doesn't work the same as in Unix/Linux. On Linux it uses the fork command and all the context is copied/duplciated to the new pocess as it is when forked.

The system call fork does not exsit on windows, and the multiprocessing module has to create a new python process and load all the modules again, this is the reason why on the [python lib documetnacion](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) forces you to user the `if __name__ == '__main__'` trick when using mutiprocessing on windows.

The solution to this case is to use threads instead. This case is a IO bound process and you the advantage os multiprocessing that is avoiding GIL problems does not afect you.

More info in http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: thanks, but although not stated in the question, I have other tasks that I'd like to perform after, such as zlib decompression and xml parsing that lead me to use multiprocess rather than threading.