# python multiprocessing keeps spawning the whole script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have trouble organizing my script to use multiprocessing. It seems that the processes are spawned but it executes the whole script again and again. In this example it will `print("PREPARATION")` constantly.
I assume my problem is with the organization of the script.

```
import subprocess as sp
import multiprocessing


def func1():
   blah
   blah
   blah

def func2():
   blah
   blah
   blah

def derev_work(cmd):
    proc = sp.run(cmd)
    print(proc.stdout)

def main():

    print("PREPARATION")
    cmd_list = [[path_to_exe, arg1, arg2, arg3] for sheet in sortedsheets]

    if __name__=="__main__":
        print (multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

        results = []
        r = pool.map_async(derev_work, cmd_list , callback=results.append)
        r.wait()
        print(results)

    print("COMPLETION")

main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiprocessing launching too many instances of Python VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923706/multiprocessing-launching-too-many-instances-of-python-vm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

idiom.

It's explained very clearly in the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods):

> Instead one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using `if __name__ == '__main__':` as follows...

Comment: I didn't grasp the idea that the 'if __name__ == "__main__":' is "protecting"... got it now... Thnaks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923706/multiprocessing-launching-too-many-instances-of-python-vm